# removing pagination meta information laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a JSON Response With Meta Information

```
{"total":3594,"per_page":20,"current_page":18,"last_page":180,"next_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:7777\/youtube\/public\/service\/category\/user_id\/education?page=19","prev_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:7777\/app\/public\/test?page=17","from":341,"to":360
```

I need To Remove That And Show Only Selected Result data ..

Comment: We'll need more informations to help you..

Comment: i am returning a pagination data using laravel 5.2 and the result contains pagination meta information like above json it has total ,per_page,current_page but i don't need to show the meta information i need only the second part which contains only the selected data ..

Comment: @AlaaMon3em  I can't find the result data in your json response. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @AlaaMon3em if you want to extract the result from the response, Assuming, you have the your result in 'result' index of your response, you can parse the json to get that index.right ? Or if you want to send only result you can use **sherif 's** method to get the result and send i as a response

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you want the collection you can get it with:

```
$paginated = Model::paginate(10);
$collection = $paginated->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your model name is `Product`, then you can get data of the products only (without the pagination data) like this:

```
// Add conditions to the query according to your needs
$data = Product::paginate(10);

// More info about toArray() method, see: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator.php file
$result = $data->toArray();

// Now, what you need is the $result["data"] element
$products = $result["data"];
```

The `$result` array is an associative array with the following keys:

`current_page`
`data`
`first_page_url`
`from`
`last_page`
`last_page_url`
`next_page_url`
`path`
`per_page`
`prev_page_url`
`to`
`total`

And you can use or unset any element(s) from the `$result` array according to your needs.